# JavaScript from $.get not being run

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have code as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script></head>
<body>    
    <div id="pieChart"></div>   
    <script src="https://rawgithub.com/benkeen/d3pie/master/d3pie/d3pie.min.js">   </script>

    <div id="pie"></div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guest271314/"
            + "6a76aa9d2921350c9d53/raw/"
            + "1864137bfd2eb62705bd0e71175048a28b3253e6/abc.txt", function (data) {
                alert("The data is " + data);
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, the alert inside the `.get...` is not alerting anything, meaning that it is not even entering that get statement. It should be alerting "abc123" but it is not alerting anything. This code does work in JS Bin, as I do get an alert message there. However, in my browser, I do not get any alert message whatsoever. Am I calling that .txt file wrong?

Comment: if you are testing this locally, not on a http server, you'll need to change `<script src="//ajax.googleapis...` to `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis...`

Comment: Ahhhh can't believe I forgot to do that. Thanks so much!